# How to select distinct records from tables which are inner join with each other

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 Tables

```
News        (News_ID,Title,Article,Attatchment,Publish_Status,Sort_Order,Date,Read_Status)
Category     (Category_ID,Category_Name,Parent)
News_Category(ID,News_ID,Category_ID)
```

I want to select top 4 records from table News whose Category_ID in News_Category table is 12 and also whose Parent in category table is 12.
I have used following query:-

```
 SELECT  DISTINCT 
        News.News_ID, News.Title, News.Article, News.Attatchment, News.Publish_Status, News.Sort_Order, News.Read_Status, News.[Date]
        ,News_Category.ID
        ,Category.Category_Name 
FROM News 
INNER JOIN News_Category ON News_Category.News_ID = News.News_ID 
INNER JOIN Category ON News_Category.Category = Category.Category_ID  
WHERE News_Category.Category in 
            (   select Category_ID 
                from Category 
                where Category_ID=12 
            union 
                select Category_ID 
                from Category 
                where Parent=12 )
ORDER BY News.News_ID DESC
```

But when i insert a single news in two Category having Parent=12 then it is showing duplicate data.Please help me.

Comment: Do you have some sample data and expected output to work with?

Comment: Suppose News_ID 21 is inserted in Cateogory_ID 15 and 16. And both Category_ID are Child of Category_ID 12 means 12 is the Parent of 5 and 6.If i insert a single record in News table under two Category_ID whose Parent are same,Then my query shows a single record twice.Please help me.

Comment: That's probably because you have the New_Category.ID in the `SELECT` list. That one is unique for those 2 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving out the `News_Category.ID` should fix it I believe.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 
        News.News_ID, News.Title, News.Article, News.Attatchment, News.Publish_Status, News.Sort_Order, News.Read_Status, News.[Date]
        ,Category.Category_Name 
FROM News 
INNER JOIN News_Category ON News_Category.News_ID = News.News_ID 
INNER JOIN Category ON News_Category.Category = Category.Category_ID  
WHERE News_Category.Category in 
            (   select Category_ID 
                from Category 
                where Category_ID=12 
                or Parent=12 )
ORDER BY News.News_ID DESC
```